# center and bold TextView swift

Tags: swift, textview

Hi all I am trying to set a bold and centre to my text view I have 3 different colours in the view but I want the 2 colours that change to be centred. Is there a way to do this? below is my code.

```
        let myString:String = DisplayableContents.texts[10]
        var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()


        myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Calibri", size: 17.0)!])

        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:74, length:96))
        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.gray, range: NSRange(location:96, length:19))

        // set label Attribute

        infoBox.attributedText = myMutableString
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
    let myString:String = DisplayableContents.texts[10]
    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle, NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Calibri", size: 17.0)!])

    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:74, length:96))
    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.gray, range: NSRange(location:96, length:19))

    // set label Attribute

    infoBox.attributedText = myMutableString
```

But 'Calibri' doesn't exist in iOS. You can check fonts in http://iosfonts.com/. If you are adding the font to your project check its bold variation, probably 'Calibri-Bold'

Comment: Thank you for you reply on this. I have installed Calibri font including the bold version. with your answer it enters all the text in the text view I just wan to centre what is in the range.